# How to add comma at the end of the line and go to next line in vimrc mapping?

Tags: vim

I am trying to achieve in this code.

```
files: ['index.html'],
tasks: ['htmlhint'],
```

I want nmap a shortcut like `<leader>cn` or any other combo,  that adds comma at the end of the line from anywhere in that line. The last character could be curly or square or anything, really shouldn't matter. And then goes to the next line.

How do I achieve this in `_vimrc`?

Comment: why was this question down-voted though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you gave it much thought at all.

```
nnoremap <key> A,<Esc>j
```

Comment: okay. got it. but, the cursor still doesn't go the next line.

Comment: finally got it going, nnoremap <key> A,<Esc>o (yours didn't go to newline but it gave me the idea and finally understood what it means) I didn't know we could do commands without : in front? thanks mate..and sorry for not giving it much though, i have been only using vim for over 2 weeks now. i didn't know what to think.

Comment: You asked "and go to next line", not "and open a new line".